# Automate turning on and off of redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to automate the turning on and off process of Redis Cluster in aws. I saw the following link for reference (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=149772). Is there a way to do it via cloudwatch ?

I am very new to aws platform.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the documentation regarding scale in/out
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-resharding-online.html It also has commands to reshard a cluster manually.
2. Check CloudWatch metrics from the Redis cluster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.HostLevel.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html Choose the metrics that will trigger autoscaling
3. You can trigger an AWS Lambda on some event for a metric https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html
4. From the Lambda you cal call aws cli to reshard the cluster as described in 1. Example: https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-lambda-awscli/

If you need to turn off the cluster completely, instead of the resharding commands just use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/delete-cache-cluster.html